# print cv::Mat element -- OpenCV(C++)

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv-mat

I am trying to loop over a matrix and print its element, which should be a simple operation, but I experience some strange things...

I have a a null matrix :
cv::Mat accum = cv::Mat::zeros(3,5,CV_8U);

Doing this:

```
for(int i=0;i<accum.rows;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<accum.cols;j++)
    {
        cout<<accum.at<int>(i,j) <<endl;
    }
}
```

I get the following elements:

0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
-536870912
0
0
0
2027945984
587217671

Why is there some random number at places where zero should be?

If I initialize the value of matrix at i=1,j=1 with number 1, I get the following

0
0
256
0
0
0
1
0
0
587202560
0
0
0
1931673600
587257437

I just dont understand those random values, I might do something wrong, but cant figure out what. Could you please help?

Comment: `CV_8U` -- the elements of the matrix are bytes, i.e. **8bit unsigned integers**. `accum.at<int>` -- yet you're reading them as **32bit signed integers**

Comment: @DanMašek Could you please, give an example how would it be correct? I tried to print accum.at<uint> as well but did not work out. And if I print the matrix itself, where I gave 1 to position (1,1), I got the following...:[  0,   0,   0,   0,   0;
   0,   0,   0,   0,   1;
   0,   0,   0,   0,   0]

Comment: An 8bit unsigned integer would be a `unsigned char` (or `uint8_t` if you prefer to use the aliases provided by `<cstdint>`).